# Digit and string combined in format

Tags: java, string

So, if I have a number and a string and I want it to take together some presice space, how can I get it using String.format? For example if string  should take 40 characters I write `String.format("%-40s", string)` but what if I have some number which should be included in those 40 characters before the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use StringBuilder to pad String with blank spaces or other characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880644/use-stringbuilder-to-pad-string-with-blank-spaces-or-other-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, using `new Stingbuilder().append()` as an argument String